# What is default value of Tabu list in google or-tools? Can I change it for fine tuning?

Tags: python, or-tools, heuristics, vehicle-routing, tabu-search

I want to fine-tune parameters of tabu search such as tabu list in google or-tools, Can anyone suggest this?

Comment: we recommend using GLS over tabu search.